# Algorithm to find english words meanings belonging (parent) categories

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, nlp

Lets say we have categories like below.

How would you check any given word and find which category this word belongs to?

Is there any API or ready solution for this?

```
main_categories:[
"Abstract ",
"Animals/Wildlife ",
"Arts ",
"Backgrounds/Textures ",
"Beauty/Fashion ",
"Buildings/Landmarks ",
"Business/Finance",
"Celebrities ",
"Education ",
"Food and drink ",
"Healthcare/Medical ",
"Holidays ",
"Industrial ",
"Interiors ",
"Miscellaneous ",
"Nature ",
"Objects ",
"Parks/Outdoor ",
"People ",
"Religion",
"Sports/Recreation ",
"Technology Transportation"
  ]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for here.  There's no natural connection between a random word and any of these categories so there would have to be some sort of database that was pre-built that categorized the whole dictionary of words against these categories.  A purely algorithmic solution would have to look up the meaning of the word and try to use some combination of algorithm and AI to figure out from the meaning what category it might belong to.  There's no simple answer here at all.  What is the context for this question?

Comment: Maybe [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) ([Demo](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn)) could help you with that.

You could lookup a word and then its hypernyms.
There's also a [Node implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordnet)

You would have to lookup if any hypernym of a certain word matches your categories...

But it would not work for (most) named entities (e.g. celebrity names).